# Script only runs till certain point in for loop, then stops with no errors:using

Tags: python, loops, search, text, exit

I have a DataFrame called urlclean in the form of:

```
>>> urlclean
Matches Searching for                           URL List URL Status
14       2   Green Index  http://greenindex.timberland.com/      Works
```

as it is derived from a preliminary dataframe the index is "14" at row 1. I have written a secondary code to open the URL in "URL List" and search for all possible repetitions of the phrase under "Searching for" (in this case, Green index) in the text of selected URL as follows:

```
for cindex, row in urlclean.iterrows():
    print("starting clea nup")
    sentence=[]
    sentence=urlopen(urlclean.loc[cindex,'URL List']).read()
    print("opening urls")

    soup=[]
    soup=BeautifulSoup(sentence)
    print("Getsoup")
    rsentence=[]
    rsentence=(soup.get_text())

    print("gettect")
    indices = (i for i,word in enumerate(rsentence) if word==
    (urlclean.loc[cindex,'Searching for']))
    print("getting indices")
    neighbors = []

    for ind in indices:
        neighbors.append(rsentence[ind-2:ind]+rsentence[ind:ind+2])
        print("opening rsetence",(rsentence[ind-
        2:ind]+rsentence[ind:ind+2]))
        Resulting=[]
        print("got Neighbors", neighbors)
        N=len(neighbors)

        for indexx in range(0,N):
            Resulting_TEMP=[]
            Resulting_TEMP=[(' '.join(map(str,neighbors[indexx])))]
            print("resulting temp",Resulting_TEMP)
            urlclean.loc[cindex,'All Phrases']=Resulting_TEMP
            Resulting.append(Resulting_TEMP)
            print("got results", Resulting)
```

I included the print() to follow upto what point my code runs, it quite literally ouputs my formerly derived dataframes, and then exists the above code after writing:

```
starting cleanup
opening urls
Getsoup
gettect
getting indices
>>>
```

it never starts the for loop which ranges between ind and indices, am I missing something? I am new to python so apologies if this is an elementary problem.

Comment: One space really isn't enough indentation to make your code readable. The expected amount of indentation in Python is 4 spaces.

Comment: @khelwood oh sorry do you mean in the context of being able to read it on this website, or in executing my code?

Comment: Both. The Python interpreter will, of course, complain about inconsistent indentation, but also in the code you've posted here, many lines are indented by one space, and it's not clear whether those should have been indented by a full four spaces or they are meant not to be indented at all. It would really help if you check and correct your indentation.

Comment: edited it, does it make sense now? I added 4 spaces before each iteration of for, as they are meant to be nested loops @DavidZ

Comment: Can you verify that `indices` is being populated? You can try a debugger or simply do a `print(len(indices))` to check.

Comment: @bendl yes I have checked, it doesnt popupalate indices, it stops short of beginning the loop, is there a way to check why?

Comment: There are two obvious possible reasons why `indices` isn't being populated: first `rsentence` is empty and second, the `if` statement always resolves to false. First is easy to check the same way as you did for `indices`, second can be checked with `print(any(word==(urlclean.loc[cindex,'Searching for']) for word in rsentence))`